# PHP security : retrieving PHP file from server, un-processed

Tags: php, security

Is there really a way to do this ? Retrieving raw .php file from the server (other than getting into server's FTP account) ? Is this the reason why there are tools/script to encrypt php source code ?

If it's true, then how to protect against it ? (without using php source code encryption)

edit: the server mentioned has php running, eg. apache-php-mysql, your standard hosting server configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are talking about someone else's server, then the short answer is no. If third parties could read your PHP source code, that would be quite a security hole, since PHP files tend to contain database passwords, hash keys, proprietary algorithms and other goodies that you don't want falling in the wrong hands.

If you are talking about your own server (ie. that you yourself have access to), then there are simple scripts that you can put on the server, that allow you to specify a path to any file on the server and have it returned as plaintext.
*However, you NEVER EVER want to place such a script on a production server, for the reasons mentioned above.*

Comment: got it. Then the only way would be to upload the mentioned script to the server and run it. Is that what you are saying ?

Comment: Well, yes, unless you want to disable php processing on the server, or rename the php files

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, you can't access remote source code. The PHP module would have to be disabled for this to occur.

But as a thought experiment, how might this happen?

Leaving aside wholesale exploits which get access to the entire filesystem, imagine if there were a security hole in an application which allowed you to insert an line into an .htaccess file. Given that an .htaccess writable by the httpd process is useful for apps like Wordpress, it's not too outlandish a possibility.

If you added this:

```
php_value engine off
```

The source files now become downloadable!

Comment: I don't like seeing your rep. 8990 ? +1 from me. ..kidding, nice answer, didn't know of this method before. Thanks as always Paul.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible if the server is not well configured that PHP files are not handles as such.

Some examples:

- Some servers are configured to show the [highlighted source code of a PHP file](http://docs.php.net/highlight_file) when requested as `.phps` instead.
- Some developers use `.inc` for files that are intended to be included using `include` or `require`. If the server is not configured to handle these as PHP as well, they will be delivered as plain text when they are requested directly.

But the developer can also be the source of vulnerability. For example when he uses a script for downloading files from the server and this script accepts nearly every input without validation.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is served from a web server that has php interpretation enabled (via HTTP) then it will be processed. The only way you'd receive the code unprocessed is if PHP was disabled somehow.

Comment: umm.. no, the server has php running. But if that's the only case, is there really a way to tinker with the server to got php disabled or something ?

Comment: No, what? I don't understand. You said the same thing I did. Someone remotely can't disable php unless they have access to config files.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a mis-configured web server in the past that had one virtual host properly setup to server PHP files via the PHP interpreter.  There was a second virtual host pointing at the same directory, but didn't have php enabled.  This meant things like the 'config.php' for several apps where visible as plain text.  As everyone knows a typical config.php has database auth credentials and other things that shouldn't be known.

So, it is very important to understand your web server setup, and make sure you aren't doing something silly.