# PHP getting the PHP file

Tags: php, security

Is there any way to get the source file of PHP like you would for HTML file or javascript from web browser alone? If so how? If not why?

Comment: Don't know why this was closed.  Anyway, google for `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps` and you'll find some articles on how to set up Apache to return PHP source instead of the output of the PHP script.

Comment: Also see this question which is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498521/php-security-retrieving-php-file-from-server-un-processed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Server-side languages are meant to be interpreted and run **before** the output is sent to the browser.

Comment: It is possible,  just not easy.

Comment: Right... when the server fails, the entire text will be printed on the web browser correct? So how does PHP script get interpreted?

Comment: Yeah, but this is dependent on bad server-side code, not the actions of the client. It's impossible to retrieve the server-side code on demand.

Comment: "No, this is not possible. "  Then I guess you could say I do the impossible for a living,  because I find source code disclosure vulnerabilities on a regular basis.

Answer (score 3):

Of course.  But only if the web server is configured to return just the file and not interpret it first.  Most web servers hosting PHP files aren't configured this way.

Answer (score 3):

In order to read PHP source code on a remote server, the user needs to find and exploit a remote [file disclosure vulnerability.](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/13966/)  These most often occur in the application its self and can be detected by using a web application vulnerability scanner like [w3af](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/).

MySQL based sql injection can be used to read files using the `load_file()` function as [described here](http://www.ngssoftware.com/papers/HackproofingMYSQL.pdf).

It is possilbe that the httpd can be vulnerable to a source code disclosure attack,  such as this one in [IIS](http://secunia.com/advisories/16548/).

Answer (score 1):

Only if the web server happens to fail. Otherwise no, because all code is executed on server and only it's result are being send to browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this - but you have the web server needs to be setup to serve ".phps" as text/plain as I've done to demonstrate code examples from my web server. However, if you're trying to poach code from a website running php it's really not possible. Not from the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would pose a massive security risk with MySQL passwords and other sensitive data.

Comment: yea... that's why I am worried.

Comment: You put the passwords *in* your code? That in itself is a massive security risk. Put it/them in a config file, put the file *outside* the web space so there's *no way* the server can send it. Lock the file down with very restrictive permissions. Don't check the file into version control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?printf($f='<?printf($f=%c%s%c,39,$f,39);?>',39,$f,39);?>
```

so, yes.

Comment: whaaat?? what the heck is `$f` and what is this script supposed to accomplish, and how are you supposed to execute it on a server that isnt yours?

Comment: Mark, this code prints itself.